# Ros2_control rover examples have odom processing in user supplied code

Tags: ros2-control

However, in the code of Ros2_control I see odom processing in detail. Why does the user also have to duplicate this processing? Velocities, times, encoder ticks, etc. Doesn't all this get processed in the underlying code? Why must it get processed in the user-supplied version of interface-hardware? Wouldn't the yaml file or xacro file with ticks-per-revolution and robot dimensions be enough, along with actual encoder output? And the motor commands, aren't they "ready to go" from the Ros2_control interface? Or is more processing needed to be supplied by the user, with times, velocities, wheel dimensions, etc. I have used the diffbot example 2, and the Rviz view, along with actual robot, shows that the robot is outputting good motor commands. But the odom readings still seem to be simulated judging by the robot in Rviz. It is moving much more than the actual robot. My robot isn't spinning at all, but the one in Rviz is spinning.

Note: I have used Example 2 as the base for my code building.

Comment: what do you mean by _Why does the user also have to duplicate this processing?_

Are you speaking of the [diff_drive controller](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/tree/humble/diff_drive_controller) or the [example_2](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/tree/master/example_2)? Be aware that the latter is only for demonstration purposes, and you have to implement the hardware component plugin according your sensors/actuators.

Comment: Yes, I used the Example_2 demo as the base for my controller. Now I need to "turn off" the simulated odom and force Ros2_control to use my actual odom data. The "mock hardware" is off, but the controller still doesn't follow my robot's encoders.

Comment: If the odometry routine can work properly, why doesn't it take as input, "wheel encoder ticks per revolution"? I don't see that required in the yaml file?

Comment: I found where to "turn off" the simulated odometry, in the open_loop parameter in the yaml file, and to set position_feedback to true.

Comment: If this is not clear within the [documentation](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/diff_drive_controller/doc/userdoc.html), I encourage you to [write a PR](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/contributing/contributing.html) making this clear.